# How do I get the right user principal with Spring-Boot and Oauth2?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am practising Spring-Boot 2.2 + Spring Security 5 + Oauth2. Following a lot of examples I am hitting a wall here.

My spring security configuration is this:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/", "/css/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and().oauth2Login().userInfoEndpoint()
      .userService(new DefaultOAuth2UserService());
}
```

and I have a controller with this method:

```
@GetMapping("/create")
public ModelAndView create(Principal principal) {
    log.debug(principal);
    return new ModelAndView("create.html", "topicForm", new TopicForm());
}
```

in the Thymeleaf template I would call <span sec:authentication="name">User</span>, and it only returns a number.

in debug, authentication is org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken, and the Principal is a DefaultOidcUser, the name attribute is "sub", which is not a name but a number in google's oauth response.

DefaultOAuth2UserService is never called before my breakpoint hits in the controller.

Where did I take the wrong turn?

--edit--
In further debugging, I think the problem stems from OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter calling org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.userinfo.OidcUserService which would be configurable by oidcUserService(oidcUserService())

Answer (score 0):

To get current principal you can use `@AuthenticationPrincipal annotation`  which resolves `Authentication.getPrincipal()`  so you can add it as argument.

```
public ModelAndView create(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {
    log.debug(principal);
    return new ModelAndView("create.html", "topicForm", new TopicForm());
}
```

Comment: it still is a OAuth2AuthenticationToken and the DefaultOAuth2UserService is not called.Also, i need the principal right in the resulting web page where in thymeleaf I would call <span sec:authentication="name">User</span>, and it only returns a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `SecurityContextHolder`.

```java
public ModelAndView create() {
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentcation().getPrincipal();
    log.debug(principal);
    return new ModelAndView("create.html", "topicForm", new TopicForm());
}
```

Comment: this does not change the fact that the principal is not the type I need it to be. It is the raw token returned from Google auth but I need it 'refined' by DefaultOAuth2UserService so that later I get what I need from the principal. For example behind that controller I have a thymeleaf template that uses <span sec:authentication="name">User</span> to retrieve the authenticated user's name. because the principal is the raw token all the tag returns is an ID number.